# how to fetch and add data in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

how to fetch and add the data in sqlite? I want to  for example. I have table1 that has 2 columns

```
column 1           column 2
   1                   2
```

I want to fetch column2 so that i will be able to add it to the newly inputed number.

for example

newly inputted number is 5 then

```
column 1           column 2
   1                   7
```

Comment: Are you asking for a query, Java code, both, or something else?

Comment: Hello sir. Im asking for both.

Comment: You have an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
public void update_db(int pass_value,int key_id) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String select = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE " + KEY_ID + " = " + key_id;

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(select, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        int column2_value = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("column2"));
        Log.d(TAG, "column2_value :"+column2_value);
        column2_value=column2_value+pass_value;

        String strSQL = "UPDATE " + TABLE + " SET column2 = " + column2_value + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + " = " + key_id;
        db.execSQL(strSQL);
    }
    if(c!=null)
      c.close();
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Hello sir. How can fetch the previous value of column2? so that i will be able to put it in the pass_value.

Comment: Ive found how to get the previous value. Thankyou sir for your help.